# iPhone 5S won't detect all beacons all the time / inconsistency between iOS BLE and Android BLE

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

Could someone help me try to get to the bottom of a complex issue? I am not yet completely familiar with iPhone hardware and nuances between OSs and devices (which I was told would be less of an impact than in Android).

Oh, if I should post this kind of question somewhere else instead, pls say before shouting at me

### Background

I have been learning swift and iPhone hardware for the last few weeks.
I am an Android developer, and our BLE powered app is working well on Android 4+.
Our iOS App however is not functioning well on a very small subset of phones (unfortunately ones that a lot of our clients' corporate tester people use).
It is working fine (the component in question) on every phone we've tried it on, apart from SOME 5Ss.

I purchased a 5S to test this, and after several days of trying on many occasions, could not recreate it, everything just worked for me.
Contrary to this, some of our testers report that it has never worked for them at all.
Our very first tester has lent me his device, and I have definitely recreated something that would cause the problems we have, but I cannot recreate it on my 5S.
He also got another 5S, and couldn't recreate it on that phone, which was good and very bad at the same time.
It actually, honestly, seems like it's only the ones painted black that it happens on (I know..)

Our app listens to beacons on buses.
We support Android 4+ and iOS 9+.

### The "Broken" state:

- starts ranging for region with our UUID
- finds no beacons, or only finds beacons from a very limited set
  continues to return these limited or empty range results for all apps using just BLE (have noticed BT Scanners seem to get devices, probably because it's not a BLE scan that's happening)
- resets device, tries again
- all/most beacons detected
- eventually ends up back in broken state, which can occur both during ranging cycles, and right when you start a one.

Firstly we thought we were getting no hits in our app, as we mash together 4 beacons per bus and no buses were appearing.
*[We only need one hit from one of these occasionally to say you're on a bus, which is why this is so tedious- we're not doing indoor positioning or anything.
Everything is fine across other handsets and OSs (iOS and [actually works better on] Android)]*

I later noticed in my diagnostic app that actually some beacons were being detected, but not the "right" ones, due to an unrelated bug (with our code)
Still, the issue persists that the other beacons are not found, and the device seems to either show all the beacons, or just some from a fairly small, but consistent, subset of beacons.

Initially, we thought it was our contractor's code.
Then we thought it was Apple.
Now we think it's our code interacting poorly with hardware prone to failure (i.e., both).

I am able to reproduce using boilerplate ranging code.
I didn't believe it was an actual issue until I got my hands dirty- I have been working with BLE for about 3 years.
We put in a TSI with Apple, they accepted it and refunded our TSI credit.
We've heard nothing after several weeks, although we collected the data they wanted.

### I think it's strange

It really seems like the adapter is somehow locking itself to specific regions, but makes no sense that:

- <strike>a)the majors ranged are fairly consistently biased- as I'm seeing very similar Majors appear when all the beacons are roughly 5 meters from me (I also have no region code in my test app except for the initial region with our UUID in it) for instance, when I started typing i had 10000-10010, 11001-1104, 12001-12020 showing up, now I only seem to be able to range 12020, 10000, 100001 and 11003. I always see 12020 and 10001 majors appearing when it's in the "broken" state - roughly 150 beacons are all the same model, same UUID, same broadcast interval etc, same firmware (though there are some exceptions, but the beacons it's biased towards are a mix of older and newer firmware and actually a few of them are a different model too, but this only implies that it's not the beacons causing it.</strike> - these were the exceptions, it is our older beacons that are being detected, some of the newer ones just had the same identifiers initially
- b)this affects other apps- surely one app should not be able to break the system bluetooth adapter that badly (especially in such a thoroughly deployed device).
- <strike>c)sometimes it actually takes two reboots to fix the problem, but it has never taken three- surely if the BT Adapter crashed it should be reboot the first time? Unless they have some user friendly 'you obvs don't need to hard reboot you silly user friend :)' Apple stuff.. meaning it doesn't properly reboot the first time.</strike> this problem seems to have been caused by the adapter not having its regions removed properly, seeing to that has meant I don't have to restart the device to get beacons detected again, and restarting bluetooth now sorts it. Also, actually going into the background kicks detection off again, but not fully, it seems limited
- d)<strike>there's no easily discernable 'point' where it breaks- you might have all the beacons, then you have like one or three, always from the same group of majors (as if it's saying none of the rest are ibeacons but this one) - implying it's falling over somewhere, somehow</strike> yes there is, once we go into the background (i.e., lock screen, not change app), then come back into fore. This is reliably reproducible
- e)this works fine on iPhone 5, other iPhone 5Ss, and everything after that. I thought Apple's thing was consistency across devices

### How can I establish more information about the differences in devices?

The device I can recreate this on is on the latest version of iOS as well as the one I can't. There's so few factors that we can be affecting that could be to blame- the only explanation that we can come up with is that this hardware is different to the other 5Ss (the ones that work every time) - and has a different chip set or something unique about it that is breaking with our code that works for other devices.

Apple have told us there is no known workaround - but I got the impression they weren't actually sure what was wrong.

I can put more specific info here, I just thought I should finally word vomit this here before the weekend in case someone sees it and it sounds familiar (that person would be a hero)

Both the working device and the non-working device have the Model: A1457 & ME434B/A (colouring and serial number are the only discernible differences to my untrained eyes)

---

### Update: 4 weeks later -

We've decided for now to get people re-testing. We think it's possible that the device we have is a one-off. We were told that someone else had recreated it when they collected data for Apple, but on closer inspection, it was a different issue.

After speaking with Kontakt about why their Beacon/ToughBeacons would be picked up ahead of their Beacon Pros, I was met (rightly) with confusion - they expected the Beacon Pros to be /more/ compatible. One theory we have is that they are already picked up by the device as peripherals because they broadcast a Kontakt Secure Profile using non-BLE BT (although it should be treated as a different device according to Kontakt, and that makes sense, but still, the non-Pros don't do this and are picked up) - meaning they are picked up as peripherals and then perhaps ignored during BLE detection. It's hard to say, there are a lot of factors, and we think it's this device being loopy or damaged.

After talking to Radius about their operation that fixes the problem - they didn't really know what they were doing as there was nothing special. One of their devs talked me through a portion of code he thought was relevant, but it was nothing new compared to what I'd been trying in my own diagnostic app.
I did find our app didn't clean up ranging regions well enough, but I fixed this before I had contacted Radius or Kontakt - this was affecting the device that we thought had recreated the same issue as the problem device, but some code from my diagnostic app fixed it.

So this is basically shelved until Apple decide they can fix it.

Here's a graph showing difference between a "good" (red) 5S and the "bad" (blue) one, as they move into the background. Blue is only picking up the beacons that aren't beacon pros in foreground, then acts like Red while in background:

[image: Here's a graph showing difference between a "good" (red) 5S and the "bad" (blue) one, as they move into the background. Blue is only picking up the beacons that aren't beacon pros in foreground, then acts like Red while in background]

### Update - Several months later

Oh the things I have seen..!

We've moved past this now, and we're not dropping iOS, so I thought I'd share some stuff, an indirect trick and some more observations. I will eventually update this and answer it and make it make sense

indirect trick - on the iPhone 5S, the "bad state" we were having where we could only pick up retrobeacons was fixed by a Radius Networks filter config change. What was actually happening is that updating it was restarting monitoring in regions unrelated to the ones I was ranging in. I found that monitoring in a region of 0000-0000...(etc-all 0s)-000000000000 whilst also ranging for our UUID actually massively improved the ranging we were getting.
It was also most definitely the thing that was fixing it for me while using the Radius App. Apple does sort of tell you to monitor until you find a beacon and then range, but we're not working like that and they never hinted at this. So, if you notice your iPhone not getting range results when it should, try monitoring in parallel, let me know what you see.

More observations -

Before, we noticed that going from background to foreground had an impact on ranging, we've also seen that sitting on the lit-up still-locked screen, but not swiping anywhere - just tapping the screen so it stays active - will cause your ranging to mess up. If you just print out ranging results and try this you'll see what I mean.

We also noticed that Airplane mode being enabled really helped too, but this was no use obviously, but had a massive impact on the 5Ss we thought had problems.

Realistically, our problem has always been (though we didn't know it) that iOS simply internally handles BLE differently. There seems to be more averaging and more processing of the range results - with some annoying effects, especially "bad" hits when confidence seems to be low.

The SE is NOT an iPhone 6 in a 5S body. It's actually more like a 5S with a 6 processor. One of our clients said this to us and we just took it at face value, so when they moved up from 5S to SE, it was assumed, yet again, that this was somehow a bug in our code and not some hardware issue.

### Bad hits

A few months ago we started doing some formal empirical tests and paying much closer attention to the results. We didn't get a spectrum analyser like I wanted but we didn't need it anyway unfortunately. I think one of the most important parts about this was re-visiting the concept of "bad hits" on the iPhone, and trying to see what they meant. It didn't take very long before we noticed two things:

- the iPhone had a consistently lower RSSI, if android had -70, it
  might have -80 (using our default beacons),
- the iPhone does not
  handle lower RSSIs well.

From the graphs we'd been making, we could see that bad hits began around the <=-90dBm mark. After this, we were seeing hits with 0dBm or no hits at all, whereas Android would say -100, -110 etc.
This threshold is either due to hardware or software, or is an internal policy. We've seen similar results between Swift 3/4 and iOS 9 through 11.0.3 and across multiple handsets. The most noticeable trend is that more expensive iPhones tend to have slightly better performance than the model below them.

That makes sense, but this all suggests that the BLE strategy is bound by some internal policy that enforces reporting of "bad" hits. This is actually totally fine for us, but we can't not have hits when we need them, especially while we're reporting around -80dBm on Android at the same time. It was evidence like this that eventually made us conclude that we'd be a whole lot better off if we somehow raised the RSSI on iPhones by about 10dBm.

We just upgraded our deployed beacons recently, and we've been seeing positive results since. We're using Kontakt beacons, and we upped them from Tx at -12dBm to +4dBm, and this has added between +10 and +20 dBm to the RSSIs we're seeing (in testing). Battery will take a hit, but we really could not care less. We are concerned about leakage, but it doesn't really bother us right now, and we'll cross that bridge when we get there.

We also increased the broadcast interval from 350 to 100. We noticed in testing that this also helped to alleviate "bad" hits- we're assuming that this is because the device has more data from scans to make an assumption about the RSSI.

The following graph shows a nice comparison between upgraded and not upgraded beacons.

On the right, we see a synopsis of multiple tests (while we were upgrading we did some tests to see if it was working) colour is device, Blue is an iPhone 7 and the Red/Green are a Huawei P9 and some Sony phone.

On the left graph, device is denoted by the shape of the node, iPhone is circles. Colouring is related to individual beacons. Users would be around 4 beacons at a time, save for any that briefly come into view

[image: Comparison of 3 phones over a day of testing. We see beacons by colour over time on the left, for the selection made in the graph on the right where colour is associated with the device that recorded that result. During a testing period, an individual beacon is not logged more than once every 5 seconds, which might be considered as a confounding factor, but this is how we operate irl]

We're showing two separate instances of a period of scanning on the left graph, the first is the un-upgraded beacons (In this graph the devices are shapes, iPhone is circles). Notice that there are a lot of "bad" hits at the top in this turquoise group, and they're all from the beacons that are nearby the device (the orange hits in there are from android devices, hence the triangles and Xs)

The second is the upgraded beacons, we've very clearly raised RSSI values. We've also almost eliminated "bad" hits - the only ones on the right are from beacons that are not around the device, and are only briefly coming into view- that's fair, they would also be further away than the nearby. There is a small pocket at the end, but this is related to user movements at the end of the test.

You'll notice in both graphs that we don't see any iPhone hits below -100dBm, and there seems to be some reluctance to accurately report on <=-90dBm, whereas android is happy either way. This is especially noticeable on the right graph, and you can see from the rest of the right graph that this was not an edge case.

So as much as I hate this, we've basically solved the problem by shouting. At some point I shall refactor this question into one about the comparison of Android and iOS BLE and "answer it" with the things that eventually led me to getting around this.

### Closing

Let me stress that, after we'd gotten away from that "Bad State" issue, and realised that we'd focussed too closely on the 5S, ~85-90% of tests had absolutely no problem, and were impressed by device performance.

However, Android was 100% and this whole investigation has basically been to account for that difference, as client confidence in Apple products seems to exclude Apple from the equation of "why is this not working?", which can put you in a bad spot, especially if your company is not experienced in this kind of project.

Bluetooth is so very temperamental, and any app that involves Bluetooth should first be built to work without beacons and then beacons should be used to sprinkle on some context that makes the user feel like they're connected to what's around them via their device.

Something else you should do is constantly try different types of beacons, we stuck with our manufacturer as we'd bought so many in advance. Not the best idea, but their beacons are top-notch, great quality, so are their tools, it just so happened that the way they were configured matters a lot (retrobeacons vs beacon pros).

Also - every app developer knows this, but I don't work for an app company so I couldn't just get access to all the devices - never let one device represent a whole family - we had had issues on the 5S and made assumptions, as a result, we wasted about 3 months finding indirect ways and using other sensors to make our app look like it was working on the 5S/SE. We've removed about 99% of that code now and we couldn't be happier. Especially since the 5S/SE are currently less than about 15% of the market combined.

Start with the loudest possible beacons and best possible receiving devices and then work your way down, instead of trying to pick a starting point and work your way up.

This has been a great experience for me, but if it had happened while I was working on my first ever BLE project for a company, I would totally have taken a JavaEE job and never have come back to BLE!! This is also still a pile of mess and words, but hopefully someone will get something useful out of it, and as I've said 3x, I will refactor!

Comment: update: I can replicate the issue simply by allowing the screen to go dark and lock itself when ranging in fore. The Bluetooth adapter comes out of lock screen all screwed up. Again, this issue is only on the affected phones and not on my 5S. 
Interestingly, using the Locate Beacon app from Radius, I can recreate the problem, and fix the adapter as if I'd reset the device - Start ranging, let it go to sleep, then add a new UUID to the regions ranged/monitored worked. They definitely do something different here, as nothing I've done or seen so far could have. I've asked them, fingers crossed..

Comment: Here is a video showing this ^ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsrf3MEDNe4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Update 2: another revelation: the beacons is it [more] consistently detecting are older versions of the beacons we're using now. When everything works, it still sees everything, but whatever happens when it's backgrounded etc. seems to make it revert to only seeing our pre-BeaconPro devices. I'm trying to figure out why it might see one and not the other, but I imagine it's treating the Beacon Pros as peripherals when it's in its broken state. I also noticed that regions weren't being removed from the CLLocationManager, properly cleaning this out on stop seems to remove need for OS restart :)

Comment: Update 3: ranging is fine in the background, it's when it comes back into the fore that problems start. We've observed some iBeacons being picked up consistently, specifically, Kontakt.io's Two Battery-"Beacon", and their "Tough Beacon"s. It seems like the "Beacon Pro"s are a factor in this. We have these deployed already, annoyingly. I can't say what the effects of other manufacturers are. The beacons are still picked up as Peripherals, and switching them to Eddystone and using Kontakt's SDK works fine (think this is because it has to use CoreBluetooth, which seems unaffected by this issue)

Comment: Update - we're now thinking that we got unlucky with the device we were given to investigate. While there is very much an issue with foreground detection, we borrowed another device from someone who had recreated it on behalf of Apple's Engineers for our TSI - turns out that device did not have the same issue

Comment: Now we're moving forward and seeing much better results. A tl;dr for this whole thread is to turn your beacons up and tell your clients to wise up and buy better test phones. Getting device coverage and looking at the issue from the top down helped us make important connections later on. of course, this is all something you'd expect from Android, but I have conversely found the consistency in Android that I expected from iOS